# Default 404 page

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am making a website, and want to set a default 404 page which will be displayed incase url is wrong. How can we set that page in our webapp?

Answer (score 2):

You can specify this in the web.config, if you have your custom errors turned on.

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="error.aspx"> 
    <error statusCode="404" redirect="oops404.aspx"/> 
</customErrors>
```

Update: As pointed out in the comments, this will work only for your asp.net specific pages and handlers, not direct urls to images,html etc. That would need to be configured in IIS.

Comment: This will only affect errors in .net pages and handlers, it wont cover the entire site.

Comment: Thats true. I think anything mapped to the .net isapi handler by iis will fall under this. but not images, html files etc. That will have to be configured in iis like you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set in IIS.  For IIS 7, open the IIS manager.

Double-click on the Error Pages icon in the IIS section.

Click on edit in the Actions menu on the right.

You can then edit the various errors - for example, you could check Execute Url on this site, and give it a value of /Errors/My404.aspx (the path is relative to the root of the site).

I would imagine you can do this for all sites or individual sites as desired.

Comment: no .. I don't want to set a 404 page in IIS. Is there any way to do inside application?

Comment: @eFriend - Off the top of my head the only thing I can think of is a custom HttpModule (and I'm not even 100% sure about that).  Is there a particular reason you need to redesign this wheel?

Answer (score 0):

You can't this is a setting that needs to be configured in IIS (or the web server software).